# bash: /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf: Permission denied

Tags: 16.04

I am running Ubuntu16.04

Upon executing 
`sudo wpa_passphrase DataRoom connect@data > /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`
I get bash: /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf: Permission denied

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Found solution at https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=116000

The following command worked
`sudo sh -c 'wpa_passphrase DataRoom connect@data > /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf'`